# [C++][std::sort] How does it work on 2D containers?

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector

I have this vector object that contains vector of `int`s

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
```

I have been trying to figure out how `std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end())` works on it. Here are my observations:

1. 2D vectors are sorted by size.
2. If some of inner vectors has the same size, the vector with lesser value of first element will have lesser index value.

I have been generating a few 2D vectors now, and it seems that these two are always true. However, I am doubting about my second assumption. Does `std::sort` really work this way, or it was just some luck that made my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorting vector elements works the same way as sorting any other type. `std::sort` uses the comparison object given as an argument. If none was passed explicitly, `std::less` is the default.

`std::less` uses `operator<`. As per vector documentation, it:

> Compares the contents of lhs and rhs lexicographically. The comparison is performed by a function equivalent to `std::lexicographical_compare`.
>
> ---
>
> Lexicographical comparison is a operation with the following properties:
>
> - Two ranges are compared element by element.
> - The first mismatching element defines which range is lexicographically less or greater than the other.
> - If one range is a prefix of another, the shorter range is lexicographically less than the other.
> - If two ranges have equivalent elements and are of the same length, then the ranges are lexicographically equal.
> - An empty range is lexicographically less than any non-empty range.
> - Two empty ranges are lexicographically equal.

In short, lexicographical sorting is the same as sorting used for dictionaries (ignoring oddities of some languages).

---

> 2D vectors are sorted by size.

Not quite. `{1}, {3, 4}, {1, 2, 5}`  would be sorted as `{1}, {1, 2, 5}, {3, 4}`.

Comment: I was too late :(

Comment: @Slava only by a few seconds :)

Answer (score 4):

`std::sort` uses `operator <` by default to sort.  Since `std::vector` has an overloaded `operator <` it uses that.  [`std::vector::operator <`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) does a lexicographical compare meaning it returns the vector that has the first smaller element.  That means `{1, 1, 2}` is less than `{1, 1, 3}` since the `2` is less than `3`.  If the vectors are of different length but the smaller one has the same elements that the larger one has then the smaller one is returned.  That means that

```
int main()
{
    std::vector a{5, 1}, b{10};
    std::cout << (a < b);
}
```

Prints `1` since `5` is less than `10`.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector a{5, 10}, b{5};
    std::cout << (a < b);
}
```

Prints `0` since `a` is larger than `b` but they have the same common element.